# Leer archivos de texto en Qt

Tags: c++, qt, txt

leyendo la documentación de QFile Class de Qt me encontré con el siguiente código de ejemplo brindado por la página, el cual sirve para leer un archivo .txt:

```
QFile file("in.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();
    process_line(line);
}
```

Sin embargo el código no me funciona porque no reconoce el process_line(line), el mensaje de error es el siguiente: use of undeclared identifier 'process_line'

Para utilizar el código esto fue lo que incluí en el header:

```
#include <QFile>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que reconozca el process_line() ?

Comment: Ni Qt ni el estandar de C++ proporcionan ninguna función `process_line( )`. ¿ De donde se supone que sale ?

Comment: No sé, el código lo obtuve de la documentación de Qt, en el siguiente enlace: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#QFile-3

Comment: Por favor, **todo el código necesario ha de estar en la propia pregunta**. Consulta lo que es un [mcve]. Si tu mismo no sabes lo que esperas ...

Comment: @Trauma, tienes razón, pero el código que incluye el OP es suficiente para visualizar o reproducir el problema, aunque no provea la configuración de proyecto (Eclipse CDT, o Make).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que te da de ejemplo la página explica el funcionamiento de la función `readLine()` de la clase `QFile`. Esa función te lee una línea desde el archivo de texto, teniendo en cuenta los caracteres de fin de línea y el final del archivo.

La función que aparece como `process_line(line)` no es una función de la biblioteca Qt, sino un ejemplo que ellos ponen para que sepas que ahí es donde tú debes hacer el procesamiento. Es decir, tú deberías crear una función que procesara los datos leídos por la función `readLine()`. Le pueden nombrar `process_line` o de la manera que te sea más conveniente para dar claridad a tu programa.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias

Answer (score -1):

Qt solo trae herramientas que piden al usuario seleccionar un archivo, tendrías que leerlo tu mismo con las herramientas de C++, no con las de Qt. QFileDialog funciona igual que otros cuadros de dialogo, solo son ventanas que piden datos.